# Firebase - There was an error deploying functions - code: 3, Function failed on loading user code

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions

A few months I worked in this project and I had no problem in deploying to firebase. I'm just trying to update some Web App developed in Angular which is hosted in firebase. Now everytime I try to deploy, I get the following error:

> Error: There was an error deploying functions

My dependencies in package.json in the functions folder:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.2.1",
    "@types/node": "^14.0.18",
    "egoiSdk": "github:E-goi/sdk-javascript",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.6.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.3.0",
    "mailchimp-api-v3": "^1.14.0"
  },
```

The one outside the functions folder:

```
 "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "~8.2.4",
        "@angular/common": "~8.2.4",
        "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.4",
        "@angular/core": "~8.2.4",
        "@angular/forms": "~8.2.4",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.4",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.4",
        "@angular/router": "~8.2.4",
        "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.5.0",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.27",
        "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.12.1",
        "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.2.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
        "firebase": "^8.2.4",
        "firebase-admin": "^9.2.0",
        "firebase-functions": "^3.11.0",
        "jquery": "^3.5.1",
        "mailchimp-api-v3": "^1.14.0",
        "ngx-facebook": "^3.0.0-0",
        "ngx-pagination": "^5.0.0",
        "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
        "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
        "tslib": "^1.11.1",
        "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.24",
        "@angular/cli": "^8.3.25",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.4",
        "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.4",
        "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
        "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
        "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
        "karma": "~4.1.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.2",
        "protractor": "^5.4.3",
        "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
        "tslint": "~5.15.0",
        "typescript": "~3.5.3"
    },
```

And the functions log:

```
{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","status":
{"code":3,"message":"Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug
in the user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the 
error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs. 
Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at 
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging. Please visit 
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting 
documentation."},"authenticationInfo": 
{"principalEmail":"example@example.com"},
"serviceName":"cloudfunctions.googleapis.com",
"methodName":"google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction",
"resourceName":"projects/my-project/locations/us-central1/functions/newSubscriber"}
```

My functions setup on index.ts:

```
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
admin.firestore().settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true });

const defaultClient = egoiSdk.ApiClient.instance;
const Apikey = defaultClient.authentications['Apikey'];
Apikey.apiKey = "API_KEY";


exports.newSubscriber = functions.firestore.document('subscribers/{subscriberID}')
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {   

    const apiInstance = new egoiSdk.ContactsApi();
    const listId = 1; // Number | ID of the list where the contact belongs
    const contactBaseExtra = new egoiSdk.ContactBaseExtra(
      {
        "base":
        {
          "status": "active",
          "first_name": "Name",
          "language": "pt",
          "email": "example@example.com",
        }
      }
    ); 


    const callback = (error: any, data: any, response: any) => {
      if (error) {
        //console.log('ERRO AQUI');
        //console.error('ERRO AQUI!!!: ', error);
      } else {
        //console.log('API called successfully. Returned data: ' + data);
      }
    };
    apiInstance.createContact(listId, contactBaseExtra, callback);
  });
```

Why is this being such a headache? I already tried solution I could find. I deleted both node_modules folders, installed, reinstalled, updated versions and nothing. Had a problem with a package but ended fixing it as well. I don't know what else to do. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to fix this?

Any kind of help is appreciated!

EDIT: I did not solve this yet, but I did a workaround using
`firebase deploy --exclude functions`

Best regards.

Comment: Can you share the code of Cloud function that is causing this issue?

Comment: @Dharmaraj I added the code for the functions setup

Comment: Please add the function’s runtime logs `Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs`.
The error output is giving you links to examine logs. Have you tried those?

Answer (score 0):

According to the error, as indicated [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#entry-point), Cloud Functions deployment can fail if the entry point to your code, that is, the exported function name, is not specified correctly. Your source code must contain an entry point function that has been correctly specified in your deployment, either via Cloud Console or Cloud SDK.

Comment: Hi, the last time I deployed, the only changes made were merely in CSS. Could it be possible that there was some kind of change in the firebase project? Apart of the source code that is.

Comment: If you only modify CSS, have you tried to go back to the point where everything was working and test each modified CSS element separately until you find this error? It would also be helpful to know which CSS elements you modified. Lastly, please deploy only the function like `firebase deploy --only functions:function1` as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#deploy_specific_functions) and share any related error.

Comment: I did, but there must have been some kind of update either on the node or firebase. So reverting back didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
```

In my case i am creating a trigger like this.

```
export const sendChatNotifications = functions.database
  .ref('/messages')
  .onWrite(() => {
    console.log('-------sendChatNotifications-----------');
  });
```

but the correct way is given below and it works for me.

```
exports.newChat = functions.firestore
  .document('messages/{docId}')
  .onWrite((change, context) => {
    console.log('-------sendChatNotifications-----------');
  });
```

For more information you can track the issue by running this command.

> firebase functions:log